# when I open an android soft, why the actionbar show for a little while?

Tags: java, android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide(); 
}
```

I hide the actionbar, why the actionBar still shows for a while.

And another question like this: I changed the actionBar's title and subtitle in code like showed. Why the actionBar's title stile show the string I put in AndroidMinefest file for a while and then changed to the title and subtitle I code in the java file. Can the actionBar show the title and subtitle at start?

Comment: onCreate() doesn't get called till your app has fully loaded.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa then how can I prevent this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nathan Villaescusa said, the activity is not fully loaded, so the actionbar will show, then execute `actionBar.hide()`, the ActionBar will show for a long time especially if the device is 3-4 years old.

As to how to prevent this situaion, Activity Theme can always be set in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `<Activity>` entry, use the `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar' theme. And remove`actionBar.hide()` in activity.